# Grab input from HTML and pass it to GS

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Context**

I'm adding different functionalities to a Google Spreadsheet through Google Scripts. One of these functionalities I'd like to add is for a form to pop up, details to be added in and an email to be sent. The form (see below) is WIP and fields are yet to be fully defined.

**UPDATED** based on Alessandro's feedback.

- New form in HTML following the same principles.
- < Script > within HTML updated based on feedback
- JS updated based on feedback

*Doesn't work yet.*

**HTML**

```html
<p>To add new tasks for a specific campaign setup, please start specifying what project, campaign, platform and phase you want to add tasks for.</p>
<p>PROJECT</p>
    <form id="briefForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
<div class="container">


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6"><!--left side -->
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="fname" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Project:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="project">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="lname" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Platform:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="platform">
                    </div>
                </div>

     
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="campaign" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Campaign:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="campaign">
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="lname" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Phase:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <select name="Month" class="custom-select">
                                   <option value="march">None</option>
                                   <option value="january">Awar.</option>
                                    <option value="february">Cons.</option>
                                    <option value="march">Both</option>
                                    
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    
            </div><!--right side -->
        </div><!-- form for teacher/student-->
    
</div>    
<p>TASKS</p>
<div class="container">
<p>Select the relevant tasks to add to this project.</p>
               <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Review assets</label>
                </div>
                
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck2">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">Send brief</label>
                </div>
                
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck3">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck3">Set up</label>
                </div>
                
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck4">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck4">Quality check</label>
                </div>
     </div>
     <br>
                <input type="submit"  id="submitbtn" class="btn btn-primary">     
    </form> 



<!-- Script down here -->
<script>
  window.closeDia = function() {
    var formObject = {
        platform: document.getElementById('platform').value,
        project: document.getElementById('project').value,
        // other form input fields...
    }
    google.script.run.sendBrief(formObject);
  };
</script>



<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

**JS** (contains both openBrief and sendBrief)

```js
function openBrief() {
  var s=SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var htmlDlg = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('tasksHTML')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setWidth(750)
      .setHeight(450);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(htmlDlg, 'New tasks for new campaign setup ');
}

function sendBrief(formObject) {
  var project = formObject.project;
  var platform = formObject.platform;
  // and so on...
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = s.getSheetByName("Support");      // Enter sheet name
  var rangeProject = ss.getRange('AA2');
  
  
  rangeProject.setValue(project)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Considerations

You are trying to reference the `DOM` in a server-side script. This won't be possible. In this case you will have to pass the forms values to the server-side script called by the `google.script.run` method.

### Solution

I see that you are using a `click` event handler for the submit button. In this case you can update the `closeDia` function and create a JSON Object with the forms fields values.

To do so pick each element by their id and put their values in a JSON Object, then pass it to the server-side function.

```
<script>
  window.closeDia = function() {
    var formObject = {
        email: document.getElementById('email').value,
        project: document.getElementById('project').value,
        // other form input fields...
    }
    google.script.run.sendBrief(formObject);
  };
</script>
```

Now you can easily parse the JSON you passed to the server-side as follows:

```
// Server Side: Code.gs
function sendBrief(formObject) {
  var project = formObject.project;
  var email = formObject.email;
  // and so on...
}
```

### Reference

[Client-to-Server Communication: Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms)

Comment: Any chance could take a look to my response? thanks man ;)

Comment: I see, please delete your answer and put that information in your question. I will edit my answer to address your use case.

Comment: Ah... I see. I'm new to this forum too. It's updated now.

Comment: Hey, sorry I've had a busy couple of days. Yes, I've worked on it based on your feedback. Also came up with a new form (which has nothing to do with the issue that we're dealing with; nonetheless I thought I'd mention it). In any case, JS sendBrief(formObject) doesn't seem to work :/